# Current click position on map windows phone

Tags: windows-phone

I google it many times but can't find a proper solution
i want to get currently clicked position on map in windows phone and add pushpin to that location so that it may be saved as a reminder

Comment: I do not want to discourage new users to Windows Phone on Stack Overflow but for future reference, PLEASE make sure to format your question a little more. It should be <Here is my problem> <Here is what I have tried> <Here is My code> <Here is any exceptions I am getting>

Answer (score 2):

try this..

```
private void Map_Tap(object sender, System.Windows.Input.GestureEventArgs e)
{
     GeoCoordinate asd = this.Map.ConvertViewportPointToGeoCoordinate(e.GetPosition(this.Map));
}
```